# How to pause/mute S3 video which is embedded in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, amazon-s3

We are hosting a careersites for customers, one of our customers provided the data which contains video from S3 which is embedded in an iframe.

Problem is the video is getting played automatically when page is loaded. Customer is asking to pause or mute the video on page load.

Is there any way we can pause the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a special reason you need to use an iframe, the usual way to handle video now is with the HTML5 video tag.

This has an attribute 'autoplay' which if present will start the video automatically, and if absent will not start the video:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp

The following will autoplay (if the devices supports this - some mobile device do not to save on data charges):

```html
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

and this will not:

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. iframe is given by customer, we dont have any control on it.